# Sharepoint link webpart to multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint, webpart

I am making multiple sharepoint pages which use a "content editor" web part, with the same content multiple times.

I don't want to create on each page the same web part manually, because if a change occurs in this web part then I would have to go over all web parts to change the content.

Does anyone know how to link one web part to the other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Reusable Content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101638381033.aspx)..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems that our administrator disabled this feature :(